# In Scheme how do I return only string from a list containing combination of string and numbers

Tags: list, comparison, scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out the way to code a method so it returns letters from a list containing letters and numbers, it should return letters up to the first number in a list. For example: 
`(up-to-first-digit '(q w c 9 5 6))  returns (q w c)` so far I have the "first" defined function: `(define (frst a b) a)` but can't think of implementing this to return letters up to the first digit, although I'm not limited to use the my defined function. Any thoughts, ideas? Thanks! NOTE: I'm limited to use certain predefined predicates like I was thinking of `keep` to keep only string, but again it would return up the first digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(define (take-while p l)
  (let loop ((o '()) (l l))
    (if (and (not (null? l)) (p (car l)))
        (loop (cons (car l) o) (cdr l))
        (reverse o))))

(define (up-to-first-digit l) 
  (take-while (lambda (x) (not (number? x))) l))

(up-to-first-digit '(q w c 9 5 6)) ;=> (q w c)
```

Comment: Might mention that `take-while` is a standard procedure in [SRFI-1 List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#Searching)

Comment: It would also look better if it used `cond` ;p

Comment: @leppie No need to use `cond` when a single `if` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Just a word on terminology: what you're really looking for are symbols, not letters ;-)

```
(define (first-syms x)
   (if (and (pair? x) (symbol? (car x)))
      (cons (car x) (first-syms (cdr x)))
      '()))
```